# Is there a word for an option within an option?

Tags: word-choice

Let's there are four types of dorms: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th.(for simplicity sake)
In each dorm, there are triples, doubles, and singles. How do I communicate that triples are the cheapest in each type of dorm?

Comment: The title and the body of your question do not really correspond. Can you change your question's title to reflect its body?

Comment: While the word *cheapest* is not business-like, it is obvious that a Triple costs the least, without announcement. All you need to do is list the prices of 12 choices.

Comment: I'm not sure what communication you want - a phrase, sentence, a slogan, a table, maybe? I agree that the question could do with editing.

Comment: I would use "least expensive" rather than "cheapest". In English, "cheap" usually has a connotation of shoddiness.

Comment: 'sub-option' works

Answer (score 6):

"Triples are cheapest across all four dorm types."

You can also say "Triples are cheapest regardless of dorm type."

Answer (score 3):

How about:
In either of the types of dorm, 1-4, the triples (as opposed to doubles and singles) are the cheapest option.

Comment: How about “Triples are always the cheapest option”

Comment: ahhh that's smart

Comment: Strictly, "*either*" works only when there's a choice of two, and we use "*any of*" (or similar) when selecting from larger sets.  "Either of" always jars (to my ear) when using wrongly this way.

Comment: It's true that "either of" is incorrect and jarring. In this case specifically, "all of" is the superior option, preferable to "either of" and "any of".

Answer (score 3):

Each option comes with pros and cons.

For instance, among the amenities of the Triples is the fact that they're least expensive.

Or:

There are four CATEGORIES of dorm here:

One, Two, Three, and Four.

Each category contains options one could choose from. For instance, the Triple option (available in all categories) would be the least expensive of all.

Answer (score 1):

You could say the triples are the "most economical" option regardless of dorm. It implies that they cost the least.